# Auto-predict join condition in Apache Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, machine-learning, apache-spark-mllib

I have two datasets :

**Dataset 1 :**

```
customerId,firstName,lastName
1,Georgi,Facello
2,Bezalel,Simmel
3,Parto,Bamford
4,Chirstian,Koblick
5,Kyoichi,Maliniak
6,Anneke,Preusig
7,Tzvetan,Zielinski
8,Saniya,Kalloufi
9,Sumant,Peac
10,Duangkaew,Piveteau
```

**Dataset 2 :**

```
userId,fullName
101,Georgi Facello
102,Bezalel Simmel
103,Parto Bamford
104,Chirstian Koblick
105,Kyoichi Maliniak
106,Anneke Preusig
107,Tzvetan Zielinski
108,Saniya Kalloufi
109,Sumant Peac
110,Duangkaew Piveteau
```

Both are csv files, I can also create `RDD` or `Dataframe` from these (in scala). Using Spark MLLib (or other machine learning algorithm), can we predict that `firstName + lastName` from `dataset 1` can be joined with `fullName` of `Dataset 2`? Also, can we also predict the `confidence` of the join?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you are trying to predict considering what.

Comment: I have a data lake which has a number of different, but related datasets. I want to scan these datasets and predict possible ways in which I can build relationships between them with a confidence factor of the join effectiveness

Comment: What do you mean by "predict" here? You seem to either have a complete match( the firstname+lastname matches a fullname) or no match.  There's nothing to "learn".

Comment: I totally agree with that @TheArchetypalPaul I believe the OP wants to predict if a named entity is a first name or a last name.

Comment: I can manually see and define the join condition as `(firstname+lastname === fullname)`. However, as we have numerous datasets present in the data lake, we want to automate the schema matching process and predict the join condition. Here prediction is not about whether the join will result in a complete match or not, but if we should be joining two columns (or a set of columns) or not.

Comment: Sorry, that's not any clearer. Can you give a different dataset as your example and show where the "prediction" happens?